# divide every number of long number in java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, numbers

i am newbie in android developing, i have a simple question.

Imagine I have a long long number, like 166516516516516515.

And i want to have divided output like: 
1,6,6,5,1,6,5,1,6,5,1,6,5,1,6,5,...

I mean i want to have every every one in output.

I wrote this algorithm :

```
int temp = 2536;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
do {
    array.add(temp % 10);
    temp /= 10;
}
while (temp > 0);
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("LOG", "Dynamic Numbers Array Index #" + i + " = " + array.get(i));
}
```

it works for small numbers (int)

but for long number it doesn't give true work,

How can i solve it to work with big numbers?

thanks.

Comment: what error do you get when there are two zeroes after each other?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava sorry, it's ok, just i can't do it with long numbers. (post edited)

Comment: Ok. What happens what you try with "long" numbers. Ideally it should work if your long number is well within the range of long supported by java.

Comment: Primitive types (like `int` or `long`) have a limit, they can't be as big as you want; I guess you need to use something more complicated using `BigInteger`'s

Comment: Got it.. u mean "long long" not "long" ..

Comment: @RamanShrivastava yeah bro.

Comment: @morgano ok i'll test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read that stuff into a string and do:

```
for(char c : str.toCharArray()){}
```

No need to divide anything and you can have arbitrary length.

If you need ints just convert by doing:

```
int i = (int)(c - '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to watch out *if* you can "cram" all your number into simple int. Chances are that if it's too long you simply cannot do that at all - as you probably noticed by now.

I took another approach to the solution, but it might not be exactly what you need. Treat the number as a string.

```
String temp = "166516516516516515";
breakUp(temp);

private static void breakUp(String string){
        int length = string.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String temp = string.substring(i, i+1);
            int tempInt = Integer.valueOf(temp);
            System.out.print(tempInt + " - "); //or whatever here, you can make function return list instead of void
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Callone {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger("166516516516516515");
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BigInteger ten = new BigInteger("10");
        while (!i.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        {
            list.add(0, i.mod(ten).intValue());
            i = i.divide(ten);
        }

        System.out.println(list.toString());


    }
}
```

output: [1, 6, 6, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1, 5]

Comment: There is `java.math.BigInteger.TEN` and `BigInteger[]  divideAndRemainder(BigInteger divisor)`.

Answer (score 0):

**split longString to intArray**

Split longString to char array and then use Character.digit to get digit value.

```
public static int[] splitLong(String longStr) {

    int i = 0;
    int[] nums = new int[longStr.length()];     

    for (char l : longStr.toCharArray())
        nums[i++] = Character.digit(l, 10);     

    return nums;
}
```

Other approach:

```
public static int[] splitLongNum(String longStr) {

    int len = longStr.length();
    int[] nums = new int[len];
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        nums[j] = Character.digit(longStr.charAt(j), 10);
    return nums;
}
```